# Why does my proof fail to show the logical equivalence of (∀x)(Fx v Gx) ⊢ (∀x)Fx v (∀x)Gx?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, fake-proofs

Apparently (∀x)(Fx v Gx) is not equivalent to (∀x)Fx v (∀x)Gx, however I seem to be able to prove it syntactically:

(∀x)(Fx v Gx) ⊬ (∀x)Fx v (∀x)Gx

(1) (∀x)(Fx V Gx)-----premise
(2) Fa v Ga------------1 UE
(3) Fa------------------2 A for v-E
(4) (x)Fx---------------3 UI
(5) (x)Fx v (x)Gx------4 vI
(6) Ga------------------2 A for v-E
(7) (x)Gx---------------6 UI
(8) (x)Fx v (x)Gx------7 vI
(9) (x)Fx v (x)Gx------2,3,5,6,8 v-E

What am I doing wrong? (Please excuse my poor formatting)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 4.   It is only valid to use Universal Introduction to discarge an *arbitrary* free variable.   The variable $a$ is not arbitrary within the subproof raised by assuming $Fa$ (you have made an assumption about it), so that subproof cannot be discharged by universal introduction.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{1.~\forall x~(Fx\lor Gx)}{\fitch{1.1.~[a]~\qquad\gets{\text{declare $a$ to be a new free variable}\\\text{sometimes this step is not explicitly made}}}{2.~Fa\lor Ga \quad\text{UE: instantiate the universal, since $a$ is arbitrary }\\\fitch{3.~Fa\qquad\text{Assumption: may only be true for certain instances}}{}\\\require{cancel}\cancel{4.~\forall x~Fx}\quad\gets\text{cannot use UI here; unable to generalise when not generally true}\\\vdots}\\\qquad\qquad\gets\text{UI may be used here to discharge free variable $a$}}$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I must review the rule about Universal Introduction and the the dependencies that justify it. I guess you can't use UI on a instantiation that was assumed. Perhaps the reason for this rule in my subproof is that 'Fa' may not be true.

Comment: @AntonyNispel Yes, You are unable to generalise what maynot be generally true.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't be useful to you at this point, but the [Curry-Howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) perspective on this makes it very clear what goes wrong. Your proof attempt looks something like (using [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) syntax):

```
prf : {A : Set}{F G : A → Set} → ((a : A) → F a ∨ G a) → ((a : A) → F a) ∨ ((a : A) → G a)
prf p = disjunctionElimination (p a) (λ fa → inl (λ a → fa)) (λ ga → inr (λ a → ga))
```

You can ignore the first line. That just states the theorem we want to prove. In the second line, which corresponds to the actual proof, we use the variable `a` in the expression `p a` even though it is not bound. If `a` *was* bound to a value of type `A`, then `p a` would be a value of type `F a ∨ G a`. You then perform a case analysis on this disjunction. For the left case, you are given a value of type `F a`. You *then* attempt to bind `a`. To someone familiar with Agda, or even functional programming in general, the code above is just *obviously* incorrect.

To re-express your proof attempt and the above malformed Agda code in English, specialized to a particular case, let $F(n)\equiv n < 0$ and $G(n)\equiv n\geq 0$ where $n$ is taken to be a natural. Your proof attempt would then go as follows: Assume we have some natural $n$. If $n<0$ then, since $n$ was arbitrary, $\forall n.n<0$. Otherwise, if $n\geq 0$, then, since $n$ was arbitrary $\forall n.n\geq 0$. Thus, we have $(\forall n.n<0)\lor(\forall n.n\geq 0)$.

The issue with the above is that $n$ isn't arbitrary, it's some particular $n$, and further, in the left case it's an $n$ known to be less than $0$. (This is the assumption Graham Kemp mentions.) This is enforced in the Universal Generalization rule by requiring $n$ not to be free in the context. Universal Generalization binds $n$, but if $n$ occurs in the context, then $n$ has to be bound in a wider scope. Attempting to bind it in a narrower scope, which in the Agda code above corresponds to the nested lambdas, would make the bound variable and the free variable unrelated. This corresponds to the fact that the `a` bound (by `λ`) in `λ a → fa` is not the `a` that occurs in `p a` which is the `a` that occurs in the type of `fa`. You end up with something like $\forall b.F(a)$, i.e. $\forall m.n < 0$ in our example.